# Can I pass an Array as a http parameter in my android app? How?

Tags: android, http, parameter-passing

I want to pass an array parameter in http request.I don't know if it can work.
And If i can do it,How to do?
Thanks.

Comment: you can use json or xml for this. check out these links they may help you http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/136900/httpclient-post-and-json-including-array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093628/passing-array-of-objects-as-url-parameters-in-request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009707/sending-a-serialized-object-from-android-to-a-servlet-using-http-client

Answer (score 1):

alternative simple version, use String with unique dividers(or delimiters, whatever) in java(android),
pass it and explode the string in php to array.

---

ex:

```
String toBePassed = "VAR1||VAR2||VAR3||VAR4";
```

and in php you can explode it like this

```
$var  = $_GET('toBePassed'); // "VAR1||VAR2||VAR3||VAR4"
$varpiece = explode("||", $var);
echo $varpiece[0]; // VAR1
echo $varpiece[1]; // VAR2
echo $varpiece[2]; // VAR3
echo $varpiece[3]; // VAR4
```